# How to align columns with CSS so that they share the whole panel

Tags: html, css, wicket

I'm trying to distribute a certain number of columns on a panel, but not with the same width, I just want that they occupe the whole panel, with different widths, so that the whole row is full with the panels.

Now they have different widths, but occupe just 70% of the panel's width.

I'm not using `<table>` or `<tr>` or such tags, I'm using CSS with `<div>`'s to make my table.

The panel has just one row and a certain number of columns.. (4,5 or 7) depending on where I'm using it.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5VT/

HTML (cut):

```
<wicket:panel>
        <div class="separator">Gen I</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="gen-i">
                <div class="column">
                    <!-- mfr -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">Mfr</span> 
                        <div class="value">
                            <select name="Mfr" wicket:id="mfr"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- s cd -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">S cd</span> 
                        <div class="value">
                            <input wicket:id="sCd" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- N pts -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">N Pts</span> 
                        <div class="value">
                            <input  wicket:id="nPts" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <!-- atv-->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">Atv</span>
                        <div class="value">
                            <span wicket:id="atv"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- p sys -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">P Sys</span>
                        <div class="value">
                            <span wicket:id="partOfSystem"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column">
                    <!-- ty dvc -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">Ty</span> 
                        <div class="value">
                            <textarea wicket:id="ty"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- foa -->
                    <div class="field">
                        <span class="field-name">FoA</span> 
                        <div class="value"> 
                            <select wicket:id="foa"></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </wicket:panel>
```

CSS (cut):

```
.separator
{
color: #FEFDFD;
background-color: #4984BD;
text-align: center;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
}

.row
{
background-color: lightyellow;
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

.column
{ 
float: left;
display: table-column;
}
```

Thankyou for your help (hope you understood what I mean)

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle so we can experiment

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5VT/
Sorry

Comment: any idea for this problem?

Comment: `float: left; display: table-column;` does not work that way – display will implicitly be set to `block`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo / I’d rather try making your columns just displaz as `inline-block`. Apart from that, with your fiddle with only two columns it’s hard to figure out how you actually want this to display on larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

You floated your `div`s but you didnt specify a width for them. When you float an item, it will take up as much space as needed, nothing more, nothing less.

Now to set the `width`, it depends on how you want them to look.

Comment: This is hardly an answer to the question; should be a comment instead.

Comment: If anything, the question was hardly a question. My answer provides information on to why his `div`s are not filling up to the full 100%, which is what he asked, and what he would need to do to 'fix' it. So I dont see how that's 'hardly an answer'.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you want to do ?

```
.field {
float:left;
display:block;
}
```

And after all fields you could add div with clearing floats.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle of what I think you mean. I kept it the same but added some jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/Rm5VT/1/

```
$('.column').each(function() {
    var divider = $(this).parent().children().length;
    $(this).width($(this).parent().width() / divider);
});
```